# Is it possible (and if so how) to Share a post on Facebook to a FanPage?

Tags: facebook-pages

I realize [Fan and Group pages are different](http://www.facebook.com/blog/blog.php?post=324706977130).
I can Share to "A Group's timeline" to a group I'm in. But That does not seem to be possible for a Fan page.

Use Case:  I'm looking at my Facebook stream and I want to share something to the Fan Page. (I could share to a Group but apparently not to a Fan Page. I have to actually go to the Fan Page to Post something there)

Correct?

If it *is* possible, how do you do it?

Comment: I see an option to share on a page - http://i.imgur.com/wiLd6.png. It's just that You can only post on a page you administer and *as that page*. You want to share it on any page you like?

Comment: it's also restricted to the public setting to the post you want to share. Friend's sharing something with friends do not have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is right there on the share dialog -

[image]

You can choose `On your page` and there will be options to post it on a page you administer and itt'll be posted *as your page*.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to Bibhas answer, I think that you are asking to post content in a fan page, which you have liked but do not have administrator privileges to?

Well, I am sorry to say that it is not possible, only thing you can do is go to the page and post it there, and also what you post will not be visible in the news feed of the people who have liked/subscribed to the page. They will see it only if they happen to visit the particular page.

Answer (score 1):

If you mention the page (@Page Name) in your status update it should appear on the page.

[image: @ mention to Stack Exchange page]